# How to exit Kiosk Mode in Android Management API (MDM)?

Tags: android, kotlin, mobile, mdm, android-management-api

I am facing a nasty scenario with the Android Management API (MDM) where the app is in the KIOSK MODE without option to leave the app, except if the policy is updated to FORCED_INSTALLED.

My question is if there is a way to leave the KIOSK MODE if WIFI drops or WIFI settings changes at some point? Is there any work around to leave the app to reconnect to the network or so?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

To move your app out of KIOSK mode you need to have change the [installType](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#installtype) to other values.

you can give value :

> INSTALL_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED : Unspecified. Defaults to AVAILABLE.

However, there's a workaround which worked for me, you can always call an intent from the app which is in KIOSK mode to manage your WiFi configurations from the app.

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
```

Note : This code is for java, you can look for kotlin [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/android/provider/Settings#action_wifi_settings)

Answer (score 0):

If you get disconnected to a saved WIFI configuration it should automatically reconnect, However, if you want to connect to a new WIFI hotspot or change WIFI settings you can do this by using kiosk custom launcher and adding `com.android.settings` under the application policy.

Sample policy:

```
"kioskCustomLauncherEnabled": true,
"applications": [
  {
    "packageName": "com.facebook.katana",
    "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
    "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
  },
  {
    "packageName": "com.android.settings",
    "installType": "FORCE_INSTALLED",
    "defaultPermissionPolicy": "GRANT"
  }
]
}
```

Please refer to this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#kioskcustomization) for more information.